# Tensorflow - building a CNN model as described in the tutorial

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, mnist

I just completed the implementation of A Guide to TF Layers: Building a Convolutional Neural Network for the MNIST data set. The training model successfully ran and gave accuracy of 97.3%.

However, the tutorial does not mention how to use this new trained model to supply own images and see the predictions. Does anyone know how to use the output of the training model to make predictions? I see in the tmp/mnist_convnet_model$ folder, there are some output files like .pbtxt , meta files and index files. But I can't find instructions to use them for making predictions on my own images.

Answer (score 0):

```
y_pred = tf.nn.softmax(your_final_layer)
y_pred_cls = tf.argmax(y_pred, dimension=1)
```

and for prediction

```
feed_dict = {x: [your_image]}
classification = tf.run(y_pred_cls, feed_dict)
print classification
```

This applies to just about any model you create